# MongoDB - A detailed change request for webhost

Tags: mongodb, centos

While preparing to deploy a MongoDB powered site to a clients web server, their IT department has asked for the following:

(The Linux distribution is CentOS 6)

> What I need from yourself is a detailed list of all the changes the
>   MongoDB will make to the server.
>
> Install Locations, Config Changes etc.

Can anyone point me to where I would find the information they requested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install Location : Just use yum for your installation .. all the location is automatically managed mostly (/etc/mongo.conf and /var/lib/mongo for files)

   ```
   yum install mongo-10gen mongo-10gen-server
   ```

Or better still just search for the stable mongoDB db available and install

```
    yum search mongo
```

1. Firewall :  If the database server and application ar ot on the same server .. you need to update firewall to accept connection form mongoDB port

   ```
   -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT
   ```
2. To make MongoDb available on boot

   ```
   chkconfig --levels 235 mongod on
   ```
3. Am sure your mongoDB config ... please note that replication and replSet is a diffrent ball game

   ```
   nano -w /etc/mongod.conf
   ```

You do not need much for the installation ...its pretty straight forward

Thanks
:)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to find this information inside the rpm which is built using the following files in the Mongo repository:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master/rpm